# How to prove n dimensional closed ball is closed set

Tags: real-analysis

I am learning real analysis and confused about how to prove n dimensional closed ball is a closed set. I.e. $\left\lbrace\left(x,y\right);\sum\left(x_{i}-a_{i}\right)^2 \leq r^{2} \right\rbrace$ is a closed set

Comment: The set you are describing is not a sphere.

Comment: @Andrew: The set is a closed $n$-ball. Not a sphere.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh ok I have edited

Comment: The set you have mentioned is not an $n-$ ball, your set has elements of the form $(x,y)$, what are $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not hard to check that the complement of the $n$-dimensional ball is open.
If $x$ is not in the ball, then $\|x-a\|>r$, so for sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0$, a point $y$ for which $\|y-x\|<\varepsilon$ will also satisfy $\|y-a\|>r$.

Comment: Can you show in details please

Answer (score 0):

Let $I$ be the $n-$ dimensional closed ball in $\mathbb R^n$ with center at $a\in \mathbb R^n$ and radius $r\gt 0$. 
Consider its compliment: $I^c=\{x\in \mathbb R^n: ||x-a||\gt r\}$

Take any $y\in I^c$ and choose $\delta_y=\frac 12(||y-a||-r)$ (Note that $\delta_y\gt 0$)  and now form an open ball $B(y,\delta_y)=\{t\in \mathbb R^n: ||t-y||\lt\delta_y\}.$

Consider any point $t$ in $B(y,\delta_y)$, it follows that $||t-y||\lt \delta_y$
And $||y-a||\le ||t-y||+||t-a||\implies ||t-a||\ge ||y-a||-||t-y||=2\delta_y+r-||t-y||\gt \delta_y +r\gt r \implies y\notin I\implies y\in I^c\implies B(y,\delta_y)\subset I^c$ It follows that $I^c$ is open and therefore $I$ is closed.